# Ternary operation JS not working

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I try do this:

```
$('#hire_button').html(data.code == 500 ?  "<span class='alert alert-danger>" : "<span class='alert alert-success>" + data.info + "</span>");
```

But it returns or `success>` or empty row. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just put parentheses around the ternary. I suspect you have an operator precedence issue.

Comment: Surely the ternary operator **is** working…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `? :` ternary operator has lower precedence that the `+` concatenation operator so you're building mis-matched tags.

However, IMHO you should refactor your code to avoid some repetition, and automatically fixing the precedence issue at the same time:

```
$('#hire_button').empty().append($('<span>', text: data.info, class: 'alert'})
   .addClass(data.code == 500 ? 'alert-danger' : 'alert-success'));
```

NB: above rewritten as the original incorrectly added the new class to the button instead of the enclosed span.

Answer (score 2):

`+` has a greater operator precedence over ternary operators. Group 'em to be clear.

```
$('#hire_button').html((data.code == 500 ? 
  "<span class='alert alert-danger>" : 
  "<span class='alert alert-success>") + data.info + "</span>");
```

[Grouping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) operator is what you're using here as it has the highest precedence.

[**MDN ON OPERATOR PRECEDENCE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: probably because it still builds broken HTML!

Comment: It builds broken html

Comment: @Exinferis now it doesn't

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$('#hire_button').html(data.code == 500 ?  "<span class='alert alert-danger>" : ("<span class='alert alert-success>" + data.info + "</span>"));
```